# Convert list of InterpolatingFunctions to data

Tags: interpolation

If I have `g` which is a list of Interpolation functions such (I cannot copy the interpolation functions for some reason):

`g=`[image]

How can I convert that to a list of data (say from 20 to 100)?. What I mean is a list of data where I could use for instance later `ListPlot` and I could plot it that way.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried `Table[g, {x, 20, 100}]` before but I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: `Table[g, {x, 20, 100}]`? But why not use `Plot[g, {x, 20, 100}]` directly though?

Comment: @MarcoB thanks! I have tried that but it doesn't work in my case (see update). I think is because my Interpolating functions are at different values of x in the list.

Comment: The domain of the first IF ends at x around 90. For x between 90 and 100, you get the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = RandomReal[10, {20, 2}] // Sort;

g = Interpolation[data]
```

[image]

The source data can be extracted from the InterpolatingFunction

```
data === Transpose[{g[[3, 1]], g[[4, 3]]}]

(* True *)
```

To uniformly resample the `InterpolatingFunction` on the domain

```
dom = g[[1, 1]]

(* {0.0472677, 9.7063} *)

data2 = {#, g[#]} & /@ (Subdivide[##, 9] & @@ dom);

Show[
 Plot[g[x], {x, dom[[1]], dom[[2]]},
  PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[{data, data2},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Building on the comment by J.M.

```
g["Methods"]

(* {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", "Evaluate", \
"GetPolynomial", "Grid", "InterpolationMethod", "InterpolationOrder", \
"MethodInformation", "Methods", "OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", \
"PlottableQ", "Properties", "QuantityUnits", "Unpack", "ValuesOnGrid"} *)
```

The x values

```
(data[[All, 1]] // Sort) ===
 (g["Coordinates"] // Flatten) ===
 (g["Grid"] // Flatten)

(* True *)
```

The y values

```
Sort[data][[All, 2]] === g["ValuesOnGrid"]

(* True *)
```

Comment: `g["Grid"]` and `g["ValuesOnGrid"]` should work as well.